# Manage more than one Animation Queue ($.stop() each independently)

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a page using the [Masonry jQuery Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to display multiple items. I have written a piece of custom code which allows the user to filter those items (based on their `class` attribute), with those which are filtered out being hidden in the page, then the Masonry function is triggered to rearrange the remaining tiles, filling any gaps.

This is working fine. But now I have been asked to include a rollover effect where, when Tile A is hovered over, all other tiles have their opacity dropped to 30%. (And when Tile A is exited, all the tiles return to 100% opacity.)

My problem is that these two animations clash.

I use the `$.stop()` function to prevent multiple hover events from queueing and then flooding the screen, but in doing so, it also stops the Masonry rearrangement animation.

I have researched jQuery queues, trying to set a separate queue for the Masonry function ([docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html#animationoptions)), and setting another queue for the jQuery `$.animate()` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) and then specifying that queue when I call the jQuery `$.stop()` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)).

But, no joy.

I know that using `$.stop()` in this manner is only supported by jQuery v1.7+, so that is not the problem.

Any advice, direction, shared anguish greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would have thought you could leave Masonry *as is*, and have another queue name for your opacity animations. Remember to specify your queue in both `.animate()` and `.stop()`.

Comment: I agree, and that was my intent. I have done exactly that - trying to create a second queue for my own animations (specifying it in both `$.animate()` and `$.stop()` calls), but no joy. I am sure I am doing something simple and silly, but I am yet to find it.

Comment: Mmmm, all sounds correct. Could you edit your post to include the code (extract/simplified).

Comment: Masonry's ["Animating" page](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/animating.html) offers some possibilities. Try initializing masonry with `animationOptions: { queue: 'm' }` to force masonry to use a particular queue ('m' is arbitrary). If that doesn't work, then the page suggests two other possibilities - *CSS Transitions* and *Modernizr* as alternatives to jQuery.